FastAPI сохранение истории поиска для каждого неавторизированного пользователя
Не подскажет кто, как я на FastAPI могу сохранять локально историю поиска пользователей в веб-приложении (например с помощью кэшей каких-нибудь) при учете, что в  приложении нет функционала для регистрации и без БД (приложение очень маленькое, не вижу смысла в них).
Заранее спасибо.

cookies, web storage и т.п.?

Ну оно же как запустилось, так и работает. Хоть в глобальную переменную списки/словари какие-то записывать.

Для неавторизованных на бэкэнде лучше не сохранять, вас так легко заддосят. Лучше какой-то локальный кэш на фронтэнде (тут я не подскажу уже).
